# Possibility of doing Masters in astronomy with only bachelors in CS

Tags: research-process, masters, funding, computer-science, physics

I have a bachelors degree in Computer Science & Engineering and currently employed in s/w industry in Pakistan, but have no degree in physics. For long, I've been interested in doing research in physics, especially in astronomy, astrophysics or in particle physics.

1. Are there good institutes or universities in Europe ( Germany,
   Sweden etc) which accept students without any degree in physics to
   Masters program in astronomy or astrophysics or joint with computer
   science? If so, do they also offer financial assistance or some form
   of scholarship to such students to meet at least one's tuition fee
   expenses?
2. Where I can find some research article that some teachers are working on so I can contribute them? I want to help through my coding skills. How to found those teachers who are working on research based on astronomy and contact them?

Comment: I don't know about Europe, but in the U.S. the lack of a degree in physics would not by itself prevent your acceptance, but instead the concern would be with documenting that your ability and knowledge of physics is sufficient to favorably compare with those who are admitted to the program.

Comment: Why do you think you're interested in doing research in those areas? Only from some curiosity or have you done some related work at some point? Why do you want a master's degree? Are there universities local to you that might hire you to assist in research, leveraging your programming skills?

Comment: I don't think so. Physics bachelor degrees in Europe are very intense. I have not seen any subject where you go so fast so deep through different mathematical concepts as in a Physics bachelor's, not even math studies themselves (although physics courses often skip proofs or long derivations; or introduce them later). They might admit you if you prove you somehow have acquired the skills of a Bachlelor's grad, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for *all* the institutions, but in general, you're out of luck. It's true a lot of modern astronomy is programming, but there's also a lot that isn't. You need to be familiar with things like the Fourier transform, vector calculus, and classical mechanics / general relativity.

Here's an example of the [entry requirements](https://www.lunduniversity.lu.se/lubas/i-uoh-lu-NAAFY#requirements) for astronomy at Lund University in Sweden.

> Bachelor’s degree of at least 180 credits in physics or the equivalent. The degree must include at least 90 credits in physics. Proficiency in English equivalent to English 6/B from Swedish upper-secondary school.

You'll have to get the physics training if you want to pursue this, unfortunately.